# Columns data into rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

[image]

Data is present in the screenshot as table format. I want to convert into desired format as mentioned below.

Table describe :

```
Table A
(branch_code, branch_name, branch_state, hol1, hol2, hol3....hol100)
```

Expected Output

```
TAMF046  14/01/2021
TAMF046  15/01/2021
TAMF046  26/01/2021
KERF047  26/01/2021
KERF047  11/03/2021
KERF047  02/04/2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `UNPIVOT` is for

```
with t(id, c1, c2, c3) as (
  select 1, 'a', 'b', 'c' from dual union all
  select 2, 'aa', 'bb', 'cc' from dual
)
select *
from t
unpivot (
  val
  for col in (
    c1 as 'A1',
    c2 as 'A2',
    c3 as 'A3'
  )
)
```

`val` is the new column that will contain values from columns `c1` `c2` `c3`.

`col` is the new column that will contain the name of the column from where the `val` comes from.

`A1` `A2` `A3` are the values you want to fill in the `col` for each unpivoted column (these aliases can be omitted if you are ok with the original column names).

Comment: so i need to mention all 100 columns and 100 times need to use union.

Comment: Who will be executing the query? User in some IDE (say SQLDeveloper)? Some stored procedure that will be processing the data further? Some backend application through JDBC?

Comment: procedure is schedule on certain time using sql developer JOBs

Comment: You can build the query in the procedure (just `listagg(column_name, ',')` from all_tab_cols to get the column names) and use `execute immediate` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use union

Eg:

```
select Branch_Code, Hol1 from MyTable
union
select Branch_Code, Hol2 from MyTable
```

etc

Comment: there is hundread column and want to featch data using dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH HOLIDAY 
AS ( 
    SELECT BRANCH_CODE,HOL1,HOL2,HOL3,HOL4,HOL5,HOL6,HOL7,HOL8,HOL9,HOL10,HOL11,HOL12,HOL13,HOL14,HOL15,HOL16,HOL17,HOL18,HOL19,HOL20,HOL21,HOL22,HOL23,HOL24,HOL25,HOL26,HOL27,HOL28,HOL29,HOL30,HOL31,HOL32,HOL33,HOL34,HOL35,HOL36,HOL37,HOL38,HOL39,HOL40,HOL41,HOL42,HOL43,HOL44,HOL45,HOL46,HOL47,HOL48,HOL49,HOL50,HOL51,HOL52,HOL53,HOL54,HOL55,HOL56,HOL57,HOL58,HOL59,HOL60,HOL61,HOL62,HOL63,HOL64,HOL65,HOL66,HOL67,HOL68,HOL69,HOL70,HOL71,HOL72,HOL73,HOL74,HOL75,HOL76,HOL77,HOL78,HOL79,HOL80,HOL81,HOL82,HOL83,HOL84,HOL85,HOL86,HOL87,HOL88,HOL89,HOL90,HOL91,HOL92,HOL93,HOL94,HOL95,HOL96,HOL97,HOL98,HOL99,HOL100 
      FROM CUST_HOLIDAY_MASTER 
      WHERE BRANCH_CODE = I.BRANCH_CODE
    )
SELECT  BRANCH_CODE , COLVALUE FROM abc

unpivot
( colvalue for col in (HOL1,HOL2,HOL3,HOL4,HOL5,HOL6,HOL7,HOL8,HOL9,HOL10,HOL11,HOL12,HOL13,HOL14,HOL15,HOL16,HOL17,HOL18,HOL19,HOL20,HOL21,HOL22,HOL23,HOL24,HOL25,HOL26,HOL27,HOL28,HOL29,HOL30,HOL31,HOL32,HOL33,HOL34,HOL35,HOL36,HOL37,HOL38,HOL39,HOL40,HOL41,HOL42,HOL43,HOL44,HOL45,HOL46,HOL47,HOL48,HOL49,HOL50,HOL51,HOL52,HOL53,HOL54,HOL55,HOL56,HOL57,HOL58,HOL59,HOL60,HOL61,HOL62,HOL63,HOL64,HOL65,HOL66,HOL67,HOL68,HOL69,HOL70,HOL71,HOL72,HOL73,HOL74,HOL75,HOL76,HOL77,HOL78,HOL79,HOL80,HOL81,HOL82,HOL83,HOL84,HOL85,HOL86,HOL87,HOL88,HOL89,HOL90,HOL91,HOL92,HOL93,HOL94,HOL95,HOL96,HOL97,HOL98,HOL99,HOL100) 
)

WHERE COLVALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

This is the way which i try to this but if anyone has any other way using dynamic query. Please share your views,